# How to convert "2016-02-23T11:31:36.23" into JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, format, formatdatetime

I am trying to convert string from the following format into JavaScript Date() object. Then I want to change the format into `mm/dd/yyyy h:MM AM/PM` using the [jquery-dateFormat UI](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)

```
2016-02-23T11:31:36.23
```

I tried to do this

```
    function formatDateTime(str) {

        var dt = new Date(str);

        return $.format.date(dt, "mm/dd/yyyy h:MM TT");
    }
```

But this is giving me this `00/NaN/NaN NaN:NaN TT`

How can I correctly convert the string into a date object?

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) I should be able to convert isoDateTime into an object just like I have done

Comment: $.format.date will convert the date object into this format "mm/dd/yyyy h:MM TT".

Comment: @MarcoAltieri that is irelevant

Comment: I don't understand why the -1 but a comment in that regard will be helpful

Comment: method used doesn't resemble methods in docs in link you have

Comment: date.js: http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can parse de string into a new date and use toLocaleDateString (plain js):

```
var strdate = "2016-02-23T11:31:36.23";

var date = new Date(Date.parse(strdate));
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' };
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options));
```

Fiddle on: https://jsfiddle.net/fcLkrwv6/

Comment: Not all browsers support the Intl object (e.g. IE < 11 and Safari) so the above will produce implementation dependent results in those browsers at least. Also, not all browsers in use support parsing ISO 8601 format strings.